# How to reverse scroll through SQLITE database table at the top of the table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, pagination

I am storing messages from a chat group in a table dedicated to the group.

Now, any time  I open this group in a listview, it displays the last N messages using this code:

```
    public ArrayList<Post> getRecentPosts(int numOfMessagesGottenAlready,int numOfMessagesNeeded) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ROOM_TABLE_NAME+ " LIMIT "+numOfMessagesNeeded +
                    " OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+ROOM_TABLE_NAME+")-"+
                    (numOfMessagesGottenAlready + numOfMessagesNeeded)+";", null);

            res.moveToFirst();
            ArrayList<Post>posts = new ArrayList<>();
            while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
                posts.add(Post.parseJsonToPost(
                        res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ROOMS_COLUMN_JSON))) );
                res.moveToNext();
            }

            if (!res.isClosed()) {
                res.close();
            }
            return posts;
        }
```

Any time I need to load more messages into the group,I call the above method
which supplies the number of messages previously loaded as its first argument and the number of messages that need to be loaded as its second argument.

The method works well (or so I think), loading the messages from the bottom of the table upwards of course. 
But there is an hitch.

When it gets to the top of the table i.e. `OFFSET=0`and then the method is called again, 
the `OFFSET` becomes negative and so it just keeps loading the earliest messages at the top of the table as specified at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html.

I want it to be that when the `OFFSET` evaluates to a value less than zero, then no value will be returned in the `Cursor`.

How do I modify the expression to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved the problem by using 2 separate queries:

I wrapped the whole process described below in a transaction.

I first obtained the number of messages on the table. Then I checked using Java code if there were more messages to be loaded..and based on this result, I loaded more messages. So I was able to detect if I had gotten to the top of the table and write necessary code to  return an empty list in that event:

Here is the code: it can be used to implement WhatsApp's ***LOAD EARLIER MESSAGES*** feature...where the loading is done from an sqlite table.

```
    /**
     * Very useful for loading a ChatRoom that already has messages loaded from the bottom of this
     * table. It allows to 'load more' messages(just the number needed) without loading the
     * whole ChatRoom.
     * @param numOfMessagesGottenAlready The number of messages that the room has already.
     * @param numOfMessagesNeeded The number of messages to load more.
     * @return an ArrayList of messages loaded in pagination style..from the bottom this time.
     */
    public ArrayList<Post> getRecentPosts(int numOfMessagesGottenAlready,int numOfMessagesNeeded) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int add = numOfMessagesGottenAlready + numOfMessagesNeeded;


        boolean success = true;
        try {
            db.beginTransaction();

            Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select COUNT(*) from "+ROOM_TABLE_NAME , null);
            res.moveToFirst();

            int count = res.getInt(0);
            if (!res.isClosed()) {
                res.close();
            }

            Log.e("table row count", count + "");

            Log.e("add", add + "");

            if(count >= numOfMessagesGottenAlready) {
                Cursor set = db.rawQuery("select * from " + ROOM_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + ROOMS_COLUMN_ID +
                        " ASC LIMIT " + numOfMessagesNeeded +
                        " OFFSET ( " + (count - add) + " )"
                        , null);
set.moveToFirst();
                ArrayList<Post>posts = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    while (!set.isAfterLast()) {
                        posts.add(Post.parseJsonToPost(
                                set.getString(set.getColumnIndex(ROOMS_COLUMN_JSON))));
                        set.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){return posts;}
                if (!set.isClosed()) {
                    set.close();
                }
                return posts;
            }

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            success = false;
        }
        finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

return new ArrayList<Post>();
    }
```

Thanks!